# Different memory usage display in windows Task Manager and tasklist

Tags: windows, memory, redis, taskmanager

I recently tried to migrate from Redis 2.4.6 to 2.8.19. As I run the Redis using a 460 MB DB file, I found this:

```
>> tasklist | sort
....
pycharm.exe                    344 Console                    1    501,860 K
python.exe                    3544 Console                    1    206,944 K
pythonw.exe                   1348 Console                    1      7,856 K
pythonw.exe                   6080 Console                    1     24,852 K
QvodWebService.exe            5392 Console                    1        208 K
redis-server.exe              2512 Console                    1  1,943,156 K
RegSrvc.exe                   2540 Services                   0        352 K
rundll32.exe                  1864 Console                    1        636 K
....
```

and from Windows task manager:

[image]

as u can see, there is a HUGE difference in memory usage for redis-server.

Anyone has any idea why is this happening??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Taskmanager choose the column "Memory - Working Set"

by default it displays just "Memory - Private Working Set"

rgds